# Top 3 most frequently occurring words in a string (python)

Tags: python

Please no importing counters. I need to write a function that takes out the top 3 most occurring words in a string and returns them in a list in the order of most frequently occurring to least frequently occurring.

so `h("the the the the cat cat cat in in hat ")`

```
>>> ["the", "cat", "in"]
```

and if there are less than 3 types of words in a string:

```
h("the the cat")
>>> ["the", "cat"]
```

Comment: I feel like the only reason you would refuse to use `Counter` is if this is a homework assignment. In which case, I don't think you'll learn anything if we just hand you the answer. Do you have any specific questions about problems you're facing?

Comment: So write your function, and if you have problems, post it here & we'll help you fix it. We aren't going to do your homework for you.

Comment: I don't know how to put them in the order of most frequently occurring to least frequently occurring

Comment: @Nick Stephen: Store tuples of (word, word-count) in a `list` and sort the list according to the word count.

Comment: I can't seem to figure it out

Comment: It looks like a coderbyte exercise to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The frequency hash is first populated with the number of times each word appears in a given string. The top 3 words are then determined based on the counts from the frequency hash.

**Code**

```
def h(string):
    return get_top_3(get_frequency_hash(string))

def get_frequency_hash(text):
    array = text.split(" ")
    frequency = {} 
    for word in array: 
        try: 
           frequency[word] += 1 
        except: 
           frequency[word]= 1
    return frequency

def get_top_3(frequency_hash):
    array_of_tuples = [(k,v) for k,v in frequency_hash.items()]
    sorted_array_of_tuples = sorted(array_of_tuples, key=lambda x: -x[1])
    return [k for k,v in sorted_array_of_tuples[0:3]]
```

**Example**

```
h("the the the the cat cat cat in in hat")
# ['the', 'cat', 'in']
```

Comment: You should use `except KeyError:` to avoid catching unrelated exceptions. [PEP8 - Programming Recommendations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations): "When catching exceptions, mention specific exceptions whenever possible instead of using a bare `except`"

Answer (score 0):

If we can't import `itertools.counter`, then let's just build it. It's only like 4 lines of code.

#### Code

```
import operator

def counter(l):
    result = {}
    for word in l:
        result.setdefault(word, 0)
        result[word] += 1

    return result

def h(s):
    scores = counter(s.split())
    scores = sorted(scores.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    scores = reversed(scores)
    scores = list(x[0] for x in scores)
    return scores[0:3]

print h("the the the the cat cat cat in in hat ")
```

#### Output

```
['the', 'cat', 'in']
```